# A movie about portals to other worlds

Tags: story-identification, movie

The movie is about a guy who finds a strange device (in a parking building, or a metro passage) which opens portals to other worlds/dimensions. There's also a young woman who wants the device, and a bunch of bad guys. (One of the baddies was a woman.) The device was created by the woman's father, as far as I remember.

The guy and woman become friends and after a chase with the bad guys. They manage to capture each of the baddies in different worlds/dimensions. The dimension that I remember most clearly is a one with some kind of cubic people; one of the bad guys was turned into a cube with his head on the top.

At the end the two protagonists went to some kind of resort world/dimension. I think it is from the 80s or early 90s.

Comment: In roughly which year did you actually watch this?

Comment: @LogicDictates - I thin in the late 90s.

Answer (score 4):

Almost sounds like **Crossworlds** (1996), but the bad guy doesn't turn into a cube when he is defeated, though it is a neat CG effect...for the 90s anyway.

Joe Talbot (played by Josh Charles) has a pendant passed to him by his father. Unknown to Josh, it is actually part of a mystical trans-dimensional device that can open portals to other dimensions and alter the fabric of reality. When Laura (played by Andrea Roth) appears to claim the pendant, the forces of Ferris (played by Stuart Wilson) show up to kill them both and take the pendant.

Also stars Rutger Hauer, Jack Black, Ellen Geer and Beverly Johnson. Low budget, but has some cool concepts and executes them well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Crosswords looks like cool movie that I didn't know about ( I saw the trailer) but it is not the same movie...

Comment: 'Something' excalibrates?